# ajax call on document ready

Tags: jquery, ajax

Im having problems with my ajax call loading on document.ready but when I incorporate a window. scroll function the ajax call is successfully rendered any suggestions on how I can tweak my code. I can't provide a fiddle for this one because I don't no how to include anychart in the fiddle here is a snippet of my code:

```
function DataStreamer(){
    $.ajax({ // then make an AJAX-request
        async: false,
        cache: false,
        url: '/APAC/TW/Resources/js/gethistoricalpricing.js',
        dataType: 'json', // csv data is text
        success: function(resp) { // "resp" variable is a response to AJAX-request
            // Append new data into the 'ds1' data set
            var line = [], json = resp, i= 0;
            for (i; i < resp.length; i++) {

                rawDate = json[i]['Date'].split('/');
                hisDate = rawDate[2] + rawDate[0] + rawDate[1];
                hisPrice = json[i]['Price'];

                line.push("\n"+hisDate + "," + hisPrice);
            }
            chart.appendData('ds_prices', line);
            // getSeriesById method returns 's1' series 'main' chart,
            // you can also use full path to the series through the objectModel, but this way is shorter
            chart.commitDataChanges();
        }
    })


}

$(document).ready(function(){
    DataStreamer();

});
```

Comment: It still didn't get triggered

Comment: @RohanKumar I think it's "anychart"

Comment: chart is anychartstock variable explaining the whole process data would be dynamically added by the ajax call which works when I use the window.scroll function

Comment: let me correct my statement data does get plugged but the chart does not get rendered like the behaviour when using window scroll function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already noticed the problem with my function and solved it by having the ajax call in the same level where the chart is drawn.what was happening the last time was the chart does get rendered without waiting for the data. leaving the chart empty. so maybe the reason why the scroll function is working is becaused it's forcing the ajax data call when scrolling to the specific part of the page.

Answer (score 1):

This would be fully working without `async: false` at the beginning. Why would you want to have an AJAX call not async?

Comment: with or without the async option it still did not get rendered

Comment: Why don't you try the same but without the chart (just for test purposes)? I think the only possible reason it would still not work would be a response code not equal to 200 from your called site.
Try `alert(resp);` on the first line

Comment: Hello I did get a response of 200 in both scenarios the data does get plugged into the site it's just that on the scroll function it renders the chart :)

Comment: So in this case, your AJAX part works, right? You might post another question which discusses your chart library or scrolling effects.